# Differential Equation Modeling Fish Farm

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

**Question** - If the fish population at a given time is 240,000, give an estimate of the number of fish born in one week.

Given

- Constant Harvesting Rate $h = 2100$ fish per week
- Per Capita Death Rate $α = 0.2$ fish per day per fish
- Per Capita Birth Rate $β = 0.7$ fish per day per fish

---

So let the population be $X(t)$ at a given time $t$

The differential equation we get is
$$\frac{dX}{dt} = βX - αX - h$$

Putting in the values we get
$\frac{dX}{dt} = 0.7X - 0.2X - \frac{2100}{7}$ (keeping it per day)

$\frac{dX}{dt} = 0.5X - 300$

Solving this we get $X(t) = \frac{Ce^{\frac{t}{2}} + 300}{0.5}$

Taking an initial condition of $X(0) = X_0$

Then solving the general solution to get the particular solution we get

$X(t) = (X_0 - 600)e^{\frac{t}{2}} + 600$

Now the question asks us to estimate the number of fish born in one week, so $X(t) = 240000$
But there is no other information so how will we approach this bit, like we don't know the value of $X_0$

Comment: Please use proper TeX formatting to display mathematical equations in your questions from next time.

Comment: Ok my bad, will take care of this Thank you for the edit 

Comment: Are you sure that the numbers are reproduced correctly? You would get something about $240\,000·7·0.7\approx 120\,000$ births in the following week, the harvest number is a rounding error here. It would give more interesting numbers with $X_0=240$.

Comment: Yes the data given is correct, the answer given is 1,176,000